# issue with compiling in VSC

Tags: bash, shell

Alright, I am completely new to Linux and commands.  Firstly I am running Linux on the remote window in VS Code, trying to locate the directory of my code which is saved as "testdoc.cob".  Ive gone as far as grabbing the entire path from the properties on the saved folder itself.

Now, when I am trying to compile it using the command `cobc -x <testdoc.cob>`, I get the error

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token 'newline'
```

For context, the file path is: `\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\home\username\testdoc.cob`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you typing the `<` `>` angle brackets? Those shouldn't be there.

Comment: indeed thaat was part of the issue.  even with the removal of brackets I am getting "No such file or directory".  But i know its there, i can see it in the explorer folder

Comment: are you actually in the folder `\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\home\username`? Run `pwd` and `ls` to see

Comment: I am, pwd shows "/home/username" ls shows "testdoc.cob"  then after i try to run "cobc -x testdoc.cob" and it returns with "no such file or directory" I cannot figure out why.  I just went through the entire process all over again, and recreated a new folder,etc. and still getting the error

Comment: looks like a bug regarding path lookup in `cobc`, probably it changed the cwd internally. Try `cobc -x /home/username/testdoc.cob`

Comment: I have tried that as well, I restarted from scratch again, and noticed that when I open the remote window from VSC, it says "To enable building and the debugger, you will need to install Visual COBOL or Enterprise Developer".  Would this have anything to do with the issue?